# Finding clicked item from a span using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML. I am trying to find the clicked item. For example: if I clicked on ups the o/p should be ups like that. I have written
like this but not getting what I need.This returns all text.

```
 $('.sentiment-text .text').on('click',function(e) {
    var str = $('.sentiment-text .text').find('span').text();
    alert(str);
 });
```

Here is the HTML code which I am trying.After I have written above code I am getting full text But not getting only the item I clicked

```
<div class="sentiment-text">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="key"></div>

            <div class="text" style="cursor: pointer;"><div class="tags alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                <span class="noun">Thumbs</span> 
                <span class="adverb">up</span>
                 <span class="verb">ups</span>
        <span class="verb">down</span>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear-sentiment"></div>

            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have solved this way

$('.sentiment-text span').live('click',function(e) {
    var str = $(this).text();
    alert(str);
});
```

Note that changed 'on' to 'live'. I know it is deprecated form Jquery 1.7.But no other way for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` for the context and target the `span` in the selector itself.

```
$('.sentiment-text .text span').on('click',function(e) {
    var str = $(this).text();
    alert(str);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f30a0g66/)

Comment: It return all words.Not clicked Item.  Thumbsupupsdown

Comment: @aniltc check the demo

Answer (score 0):

So rather that putting the handler on the div why not target the spans within `.text` and report the text

```js
$('.text span').on('click', function(e) {
  var str = $(this).text();
  alert(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentiment-text">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="key"></div>

    <div class="text" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <div class="tags alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
        <span class="noun">Thumbs</span> 
        <span class="adverb">up</span>
        <span class="verb">ups</span>
        <span class="verb">down</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear-sentiment"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
$('.text span').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('.sentiment-text .text').find('span').on('click',function(e) {
    var str = $(this).text();
    alert(str);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.sentiment-text span').on('click',function(e) {
        var str = $(this).text();
        alert(str);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentiment-text">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="key"></div>

            <div class="text" style="cursor: pointer;"><div class="tags alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                <span class="noun">Thumbs</span> 
                <span class="adverb">up</span>
                 <span class="verb">ups</span>
        <span class="verb">down</span>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear-sentiment"></div>

            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Its not working in page.I agree this workd in demo But not in my page.I used same above code & html

Comment: Do you see any error in the developer console of the browser? Did you run the exact same code? There must be some difference.

Comment: there is no error,but still the code is not working in my page.I am not getting an laert when I click on text